# Why does my inline style not work CSS

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I'm pretty new at this. I can't figure out why the "CSS" fill overrides my "inline" fill.

```
#label_x,
#label_y {
  font-size: 130% !important;
}
rect {
  fill: #4aaeea;
}
#chart text {
  fill: black;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: end;
}
.axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #aaa;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
body {
  background: #fff;
  color: #eaeaea;
  padding: 10px;
}
.ch2 {
  fill: #e50000;
}
```

... bunch of (D3) JavaScript:

```
bar.append("rect")
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.with_Mobile_ALL);
  })
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return xScale.rangeBand() + (padding) / 2.2;
    //+ x.rangeBand() / 2 + (padding/2 + (i+1)*0.1) ;   
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return h - yScale(d.with_Mobile_ALL) + top_padding;
  })
  .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand()) //set width base on range on ordinal data
  .on("mouseover", function() {
    d3.select(this)
      .attr("fill", "orange")
  });
```

I inspected the tags and it shows:

```
<rect y="88.19999999999999" x="39.18181818181818" height="336.8" width="21" 
fill="orange"></rect>
```

But it also shows (in CSS inspector) a line through the orange fill like it has been overridden by the 'rect' style in the CSS above. Any idea why this would be happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you explain that a little more? Shouldn't the inline "fill" override anything cascading as it has higher specificity?

Comment: Because you are not using CSS to fill the element.

Comment: What do i need to change? And conceptually, can you explain what I am doing wrong? CSS sets the fill, I update it by setting an inline fill property.

Comment: @SidR check my answer, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use inline `style` attribute instead of just plain `fill`:

```
<rect y="88.19999999999999" x="39.18181818181818" height="336.8" width="21" style="fill: orange;"></rect>
```

Since the `fill` attribute is not considered a CSS value, any CSS in your external files will override this value.

If you really want the orange to persist you can set an `!important` rule after `orange`. However, since it already has the highest priority, this shouldn't be needed.